# NHibernate Configuration in web.config - use existing connectionstring

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

I have my NHibernate configuration successfully set up in my web.config file.  However, I am also using ASP.NET Membership which requires a connectionstring to be defined in the connectionStrings element.  Is there a way I can make my NHibernate configuration use this value so I don't need to define the connection string twice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use connection.connection_string_name element in the NHibernate configuration. Have a look [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html). Then NHibernate will get connection string by name from web.config file

**You need to use the `connection.connection_string_name` attribute in the configuration**:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="default" connectionString="server=(local);etc." />
</connectionStrings>

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.connection_string_name">default</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

With fluent configuration you can do the following

```
ConnectionString(c=>c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("YourConnStrName"))
```

With NHibernate configuration API you can do the following:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
{
    db.ConnectionStringName = "default";             
});
```

Comment: I wish you quoted the solution to give me hints as the page is not found anymore :(

Comment: http://community.devpinoy.org/blogs/bonskijr/archive/2007/04/08/using-connectionstring-section-in-nhibernate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to sly's answer, you can do this using FluentNHibernate like this (in your fluent config):

```
.ConnectionString(c=>c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("con_development"))
```